# How do I maintain server time on the client side?

Tags: reactjs

I'm building an application with React (without SSR) and I would like to fetch the server time in the application initialization, and maintain the time in sync with the server time. Is there a way I could do this?

So what would go in the commented portion of this code?

```
api
  .fetchTime()
  .then(serverTime => {
    // Sync client time with serverTime here...
  })
  .catch(error => ...);
```

Comment: How is the server time different from the client time? Perhaps just evaluate the time at the point of the request... hopefully the server doesn't get swallowed by a black hole or travel faster than the speed of light....let alone observe dst

Comment: This is assuming that the client computer does not have time properly synchronized with the "real" time.

Comment: Not sure what you mean but can you add a Date header from the server on all responses or store the date on the client after the response is received.

Comment: Since the client is able to manually adjust the clock, then it is possible that the client's time is out of sync from the server's clock. So I want to ensure that the client uses the server time to calculate certain values.

Answer (score 1):

You could compute the milliseconds offset from the server time you got and your client side time. For example (this code below uses `momentjs`):

```
const { data: serverTime } = await ServerService.getServerTime();
const computedServerMillisecondsOffset = moment(serverTime).diff(moment());
```

and then use the `computedServerMillisecondsOffset` to sync the client time with the server's time:

```
const currentDateTimeMoment = moment().add('milliseconds', serverMillisecondsOffset);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you mean that the client should use the same timezone as the server, you could just implement an endpoint that returns the timezone and call it from your client. Then you can set your clients timezone (however it is used) according to the fetched one.

If you want to have real-time communication between server and client, you should be looking into web sockets.